# Angular - Dynamically loading script without script.src in a component

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal

I have a requirement in my project to integrate with PayPal's Checkout experience. As such, per their documentation, I have to use the script found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/set-up-payments/#step-1-add-payment-buttons-to-accept-payments) (Step 1) to render the PayPal buttons.

In Step 1, it recommends hitting an endpoint on the developer's server-side, which then calls PayPals REST endpoints. Their example passes no details in regards to what to charge ("purchase_unit" -> "amount" -> "value" as described in their API documentation and demonstrated in [Step 2](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/set-up-payments/#step-2-set-up-your-server-to-create-an-order)), and the amount I need to charge can change based on what the user has selected in the UI.

So, I first explored how I can load this script dynamically in my component. I came up with the following solution in a component. **Disregard the onapprove section; once I can find a better solution for the first callback, I will know how to proceed better for the second one**:

```
onPaymentOptionChanged(option: string): void {
   if (option === 'payNow') {
      const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      const orderCaptureEndpoint = `${environment.baseApiUrl}/payment`;
      const reqBody: string = JSON.stringify({
        productionId: this.selectedProduction.id,
        numberOfRegistrants: this.completedSelectedEligibleRegistrants.length
      });
      script.text = `
    paypal.Buttons({
      createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        return fetch('${orderCaptureEndpoint}', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify(${reqBody})
        }).then(function (res) {
          return res.json();
        }).then(function (data) {
          return data.id;
        });
      },
      onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return fetch('/my-server/capture-order/' + data.orderID, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).then(function (res) {
          if (!res.ok) {
            alert('Something went wrong');
          }
        });
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    `;

      this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, script);
    }
  }
```

Now, this is working, but it is cringey... If this code fires multiple times, I have a bunch of scripts rendered in the body node of the DOM. No bueno.

So, I figured, ultimately, that this could work if I could ensure that this script isn't getting duplicated a bunch of times in the DOM. I would think the following solutions to this problem are feasible, but I don't know how to implement these solutions:

1. Remove any scripts that have no `src` attribute when this code fires *before* rendering this script tag
2. Save the script (perhaps in `assets/`) and somehow make it dynamic enough to pass a request body that I need to pass to my server-side API, then render it. I could then specifcally "target" the script I want to remove by `src` to start with a "clean slate" when this code fires.

I have little confidence in my strategy to solve this problem; I'm thinking it's likely this is not the pattern I want to follow when trying to implement this feature. I'd be grateful if anyone knows a better way and wouldn't mind sharing.

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you just create the script once? The callbacks will do the work and send correct data to the server

Comment: @David see the script above, particularly `reqBody`. That object will change based on a user’s selections. Also, what if `option` is “payNow,” and the script is appended, but then they switch payment options, and then switch back such that the option is “payNow” again? I’d have two of the same scripts appended

Comment: It is my understanding that the callback is only called following user action, so your reqBody will be set with correct values if it was created in the callback and not beforehand. What are your other payment options, not PayPal right? You could just add the script and hide/show the buttons if the paymentmethis is pay now. But I don't know PayPal so I may be wrong...

Comment: So a user has a selection of payment options. With the code above, if a user selects Pay Now, then toggles to something else, then toggles back to Pay Now, I’ve now added two scripts to the dom

Comment: Edge-ish case, sure, but still not something I want my app to be doing. If I could only delete/remove the script _first_ if it exists, I can prevent the script from being added multiple times

Comment: Then just add an id to the script tag and remove the script identified by that id if it exists?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you.